# editText to & from char array without using strings

Tags: android, arrays

Can anyone tell me:
1. How to get the characters from EditText into a char array without using a string
and
2. How to display the contents of a char array in TextView or EditText, again without using a string.
I can do it if I use a string as an intermediate step, but I don't want to do that for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

To read an EditText directly into charArray without using String.

```
    val password:CharArray = CharArray(editText.length())
    editText.text.getChars(0, editText.length(), password, 0)
```

To write into an editText without using String

```
    editText.setText(password, password.size, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the strings is stored in the array data, which will be eventually GC-ed (or you may even overwrite it by filling up the array with `null`, so the array memory will no longer contain references to particular `String` instances).

So if somebody will find the strings content in `String` pool memory (that may be kept intact for much longer time, than the GC managed memory pool), they will have to figure out which 10 strings were together in the array - from the strings content itself.

Then again if your code is creating and assigning the array and 10 strings in the same place and time, it's very likely the `String` pool memory will allocate all 10 strings near each other, so even without the array data it may be easy to spot those 10 strings belong to each other (especially if the content of sensitive strings is distinct from other ordinary strings you use in the code).

You may consider creating your own "SecureString" class implementing `CharSequence` interface over `char[]`, and having destructor cleaning up the content.. oh wait, this is stupid Java, not C++. Hmmm... bad luck then, you would have to call some `.wipe()` method manually to make sure those "SecureString" instances get wiped out as soon, as you want it.

And of course you would have to guard yourself to not cast those into `String` ... which may happen quite easily if you implement `CharSequence`, so that's probably not very clever idea, from security point of view it's maybe best to have some `SecureString` class which doesn't implement any common interface (and overloads `toString` to return something non-sensitive, maybe even removing reference address, maybe just few asterisks for fun). And just endure the pain of using it as such.

Answer (score 0):

To create passwords that can be cleaned up safely, use `char[]` and fill it with `0` as soon as password verification is done and you no longer need the password.

```
//example password
char[] pass = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '_', 'p', 'a', 's', 's'};

//validate your password here
boolean isValid = validatePass(pass);

//now explicitly override the password's characters
for (int c = 0; c < pass.length; c++)
    pass[c] = 0;

//do something depending isValid
if (isValid) {
    //show logged user or whatever
} else {
    //show error message or whatever
}
```